# cascade delete (soft and hard delete) ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cascade, soft-delete

So here is the problem:
Hard delete is quite obvious that you destroyed the parent and the child should get destroyed. and using `dependent: :destroy` for it works fine and when ever parent gets destroyed the child gets destroyed.

about confuse about soft delete. if i want to soft delete user and for that i wanted to update a field in user `deleted_at: Time.now`. its called a soft delete but i want to destroy/null all the associations/dependent of user when i update deleted_at field.

how is it possible without using any gem.

Comment: What's wrong with using a gem? This is a non-trivial problem, but the [paranoia](https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia) library is a widely used and comprehensive solution.

Comment: I've seen plenty of flawed attempts to re-invent this wheel over my career; my advice would be to just use a library!!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use gem, that will handle all tricky cases, that can be not covered with your own solution.

But if you don't want to have an additional library in your project, then you can implement something similar using ActiveRecord callbacks.
Though callbacks are often treated as bad practice, in this situation they can be helpful.

You can use `before_destroy` callback http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html
that will be triggered before models `destroy` method is invoked.
Inside callback's body you can remove all related data.

Also, don't forget to override `destroy` method at model definition, to mark record as removed instead of real deletion.